# Prevent icon wrapping next to button on small resolution with Bootstrap v.3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Icon from the code below jumps to the next row on small resolutions (just resize preview section on plnkr). How to prevent this?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">some content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <button class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
      <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pmFKawp8w1eLIfIwdtDS?p=preview)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest fix would be to wrap them in a simple div with `display:flex;`:

```css
.flex-bind {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">some content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="flex-bind">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
        <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could use `white-space:nowrap` on that wrapper, if your button doesn't have multiple lines of text. If it does, you'd need to add in `white-space:normal;` for the button.

But `display:flex;` should do just fine. It also allows you to control how the two are displayed in relation to each other, using properties such as `align-items` and `align-content` on the flex parent or `align-self` on them (the children).

Don't forget to [`prefix`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)